# How do I change the message "Another version of this product is already installed."

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, setup-project

I've created an installation program using a setup project in Visual Studio 2010. If I install my program, and then when it has completed I run the installation again, I get the following error message:

```
Another version of this product is already installed.  
Installation of this version cannot continue.  To configure or remove the 
existing version of this product, use Add/Remove Programs on the Control Panel.
```

While the information in the message is mostly correct, the last sentence about "Add/Remove Programs on the Control Panel" is no longer correct. In Windows 7/2008, this is called "Programs --> Uninstall a program" or "Programs and features" in the Control Panel and not "Add/Remove Programs".

Is there some way to change the above error message to something more like "To remove the existing version of this product, use the Control Panel"?

I have looked in the MSI using Orca but have not found any string matching the one above. I'm thinking that maybe this message text is actually a part of the Windows Installer installation in Windows?

Comment: Yes, I think it's part of the installer infrastructure; It's been a while since I played with MSIs, but I think you can change a setting to allow version overwrites, then check for older versions in the install stage script.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this message is given by Windows Installer and unfortunately you cannot change it. A workaround would be to create a EXE wrapper over the MSI in which you are looking for a product with the same product code and remove it. However, I don't see why do you need to worry about this message as it usually appears only during development time, because your users will never have access to multiple MSI packages of your applications, with the same product code.

Comment: The users will see this message if they run the same installation program twice, right? I mean the very same MSI file in the same folder. So the users will not need to have access to multiple MSI packages of our applications with the same product code.

Comment: Running the MSI again after it was installed will make it enter in maintenance phase, i.e. present the user with the options to remove/repair/modify it.